# Can someone explain what this line does?

Tags: solidity, events

```
event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner)
```

What is the purpose of this line?

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line defines an event which can be emitted after something takes place. Clients can then listen for this event and react when it happens. http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events

Comment: Is it necessary for the ownership of a contract to be transferred? Or is it just an extra functionality?

Comment: No.. smart contracts can't be edited once deployed. So its good to put it in there just in case.

Comment: But we can still change the owner address without the event. What do you mean?